# Recoding empty spaces in a dataset to NA using R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with lots of empty spaces ("" in place of NA).I would like to recode those empty spaces as NA (i would like to use some imputation packages like Mice from R ecosystem). To this end, I am trying the following code:

```
emptyToNA <- function(x){
  y <- data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=nrow(x),ncol=ncol(x)))
  for(i in ncol(x)){
    for(j in nrow(x)){
      if(x[j,i] != ""){
        y[j,i] = x[j,i]
      }
    }
  }
  return(y)
}
```

However, I am getting this error:`Error in if (x[j, i] != "") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`. So I believe the condition within the `if` clause is not correctly evaluating.

But when I am just checking `data[j,i] != ""` for some values of `i` and `j`, it correctly evaluates to `TRUE/FALSE`. The error occurs only when I am using the function.

I couldn't figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other two answers point you toward better practice, but there might be good reason to explain what could have made the test succeed. Do not just test for inequality if there are any missing values.

```
>  if( NA ){print(TRUE)}
Error in if (NA) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
> if( TRUE ){print(TRUE)}
[1] TRUE
```

Use

```
if ( !is.na(x[j,i]) && x[j,i] != ""){ y[j,i] = x[j,i] }
```

That way when `x[j,i]` is NA the test for inequality will not throw an error. (Nothing is ever equal to or not equal to NA.) The first logical test settles the issue when conjunctions are tested since it doesn't matter what the second items value is, so the second clause never gets evaluated if there's a NA.

```
>   FALSE && NA
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think looping through elements is a good practice in these kind of operations because you can easily make it an array-operation, which tends to be much faster. For example,

```
y = x
y[x==""] = NA
```

Will do what you want. For example,

```
> x = matrix("", 3, 3)
> y = x
> y[x==""] = NA
> y
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
  [1,] NA   NA   NA  
  [2,] NA   NA   NA  
  [3,] NA   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 3):

One option to consider it to use `type.convert` which has an `na.strings` argument, just like `read.table` and family.

Here's an example:

```
A <- B <- data.frame(
  v1 = c("", "A", "B x"),
  v2 = c(" ", "", "X"),
  v3 = c("Z", "     ", "y"))
A # and B
#    v1 v2    v3
# 1            Z
# 2   A         
# 3 B x  X     y

## Convert just "", but not spaces
A[] <- lapply(A, function(x) {
  type.convert(as.character(x), na.strings = "")
})

A
#     v1   v2    v3
# 1 <NA>          Z
# 2    A <NA>      
# 3  B x    X     y
```

This is the approach that I took when I wrote [`makemeNA`](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/makemeNA.R) as part of my GitHub-only ["SOfun" package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun).

Here are a couple of examples:

```
library(SOfun)
makemeNA(B, "", FALSE)               ## Just ""
#     v1   v2    v3
# 1 <NA>          Z
# 2    A <NA>      
# 3  B x    X     y
makemeNA(B, "^[ ]+$", fixed = FALSE) ## Both "" and spaces
#     v1   v2   v3
# 1 <NA> <NA>    Z
# 2    A <NA> <NA>
# 3  B x    X    y
```

Comment: Thanks everybody who shared their opinion/comments/suggestions. All of the above comments are helpful to my understanding. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

this doesnt directly answer your question, however if you just simply want to change "" to NA, the following (shorter) code will work just fine:

lets say df is your dataframe:

```
df[df==""]<- NA
df
```