# Find and replace values by NA for all columns in DataFrame

Tags: r, data-analysis, na, data-cleaning

```
Age <- c(90,56,51,'NULL',67,'NULL',51)
Sex <- c('Male','Female','NULL','male','NULL','Female','Male')
Tenure <- c(2,'NULL',3,4,3,3,4)
df <- data.frame(Age, Sex, Tenure)
```

In the above example, there are 'NULL' values as character/string formate.
I am trying to impute NA in place of 'NULL' values. I was able to it for a single column as `df$age[which(df$Age=='NULL)]<-NA'` However I don't want to write this for all columns.

How to apply similar logic to all columns so that all the `'NULL'` values of `df` are converted to `NAs`? I am guessing that `apply` or custom defined function or for loop will do it.

Comment: Check out my `makemeNA` function, described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29445422/1270695) and available from [here](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun). You could then just do `makemeNA(df, "NULL")`.

Comment: poss duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357743/replacing-character-values-with-na-in-a-data-frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dplyr` to `replace` the `'NULL'` values in all the columns and then convert the type of the columns with `type.convert`.  Currently, all the columns are `factor` class (assuming that 'Age/Tenure' should be `numeric/integer` class)

```
library(dplyr)
res <- df %>%
         mutate_all(funs(type.convert(as.character(replace(., .=='NULL', NA)))))
str(res)
#'data.frame':   7 obs. of  3 variables:
#$ Age   : int  90 56 51 NA 67 NA 51
#$ Sex   : Factor w/ 3 levels "Female","male",..: 3 1 NA 2 NA 1 3
#$ Tenure: int  2 NA 3 4 3 3 4
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am trying to apply this logic to my larger data frame, which also consists a column as date time class which has few 'NULL' values in it. However, I am getting an Error saying ```Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: character string is not in a standard unambiguous format.```

Comment: @AshishSahu  Assuming that the structure of the data is similar to the example you showed, it should work.  Please check the `str(df)` with the `str(yourlargerdata)` to see if there are any differences in class.

Comment: I figured it out. I guess, My ```str(myDataFrame)``` had a few columns as Date Time class, which included NULL values in it. So while doing ```mutate_all``` or ```replace```  function, it was throwing Evaluation Error. To overcome this I converted all the column as.character formate and did the imputation later on, which worked for me.

Comment: @AshishSahu  I guess you have `POSIXlt` column which may not be supported.   Instead it should be `POSIXct`

Answer (score 14):

base R solution

```
replace(df, df =="NULL", NA)
```

Answer (score 4):

One can even use to replace in one step:

```
df[df=="NULL"] <- NA
```